# Has the "multicolumn" package been replaced? What happened to it?

Tags: multicolumn, multicol

I used to make use of the `multicolumn` package. Today, that's apparently no longer available via CTAN and `tlmgr`. What happened to `multicolumn` making it no longer available? The nearest matching package that I see is [multicol](https://ctan.org/pkg/multicol) and I wondered if that's a *next-generation and/or replacement* for `multicolumn`.

For context, I'm looking back at a 2020 project where `tlmgr install multicolumn` may have been valid, and, where a snippet like this was useful ... although, I don't see any `\usepackage` for `multicolumn` in the header section:

```
\begin{footnotesize}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{l|
>{\columncolor[HTML]{D9D9D9}}r |
>{\columncolor[HTML]{D9D9D9}}r |
>{\columncolor[HTML]{D9D9D9}}r |
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}r |
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}r |
>{\columncolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}}r |
>{\columncolor[HTML]{D9D9D9}}r |
>{\columncolor[HTML]{D9D9D9}}r |
>{\columncolor[HTML]{D9D9D9}}r |}
\cline{2-10}
                                                        & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{D9D9D9}PlantUML}                                                                                                    & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}TabulaPDF}                                                                                                   & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{D9D9D9}SimpleXML}                                                                                                   \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\textbf{}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{D9D9D9}$A$} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{D9D9D9}$B_1$} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{D9D9D9}$B_2$} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}$A$} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}$B_1$} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}$B_2$} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{D9D9D9}$A$} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{D9D9D9}$B_1$} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{D9D9D9}$B_2$} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Smells}    & \shortstack{ \\ 8 \\ 6* }                           & 9                                                  & 21                                                 & 13                                             & 2                                                  & 6                                                  & 13                                             & n/a                                                & 26                                                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Debt}      & \shortstack{ \\ 66 \\ 62* }                         & -26                                                & 125                                                & 81                                             & 30                                                 & 57                                                 & 114                                            & n/a                                                & 178                                                \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}C.Dty\%}    & 0.0                                            & -0.1                                               & 0.0                                                & 0.6                                            & 0.0                                                & 0.0                                                & -0.1                                           & n/a                                                & 1.0                                                \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}C.Line}    & 41                                             & -19                                                & 73                                                 & 36                                             & 0                                                  & 0                                                  & 0                                              & n/a                                                & 36                                                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}C.Blks}    & 3                                              & -3                                                 & 8                                                  & 2                                              & 0                                                  & 0                                                  & 0                                              & n/a                                                & 2                                                  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}C.Files}   & 0                                              & -1                                                 & 0                                                  & 1                                              & 0                                                  & 0                                                  & 0                                              & n/a                                                & 2                                                  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}LOC}       & \shortstack{ \\ 101 \\ 81* }                        & 36                                                 & 133                                                & 102                                            & 48                                                 & 116                                                & 120                                            & n/a                                                & 289                                                \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Stmt.}     & \shortstack{ \\ 47 \\ 36* }                         & 7                                                  & 61                                                 & 57                                             & 10                                                 & 56                                                 & 79                                             & n/a                                                & 112                                                \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Func.}     & 0                                              & 4                                                  & 5                                                  & 3                                              & 10                                                 & 12                                                 & 7                                              & n/a                                                & 24                                                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Files}     & 0                                              & 0                                                  & 0                                                  & 1                                              & 2                                                  & 3                                                  & 1                                              & n/a                                                & 3                                                  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Class}     & 0                                              & 0                                                  & 0                                                  & 1                                              & 1                                                  & 2                                                  & 1                                              & n/a                                                & 3                                                  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Cyclo.}    & \shortstack{ \\ 22 \\ 17* }                         & 7                                                  & 22                                                 & 10                                             & 10                                                 & 20                                                 & 35                                             & n/a                                                & 47                                                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Cogn.}     & \shortstack{ \\ 39 \\ 34* }                         & 2                                                  & 21                                                 & 9                                              & 0                                                  & 13                                                 & 31                                             & n/a                                                & 31                                                 \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}R.Time}    & 0                                              & 6                                                  & 6                                                  & 0                                              & 6                                                  & 6                                                  & 0                                              & n/a                                                & 3                                                  \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}M.Time}    & \shortstack{ \\ 13.5 \\ 8.5* }                      & w.i.p                                              & 8.5                                                & 3                                              & w.i.p                                              & 17                                                 & 4.5                                            & n/a                                                & 4.5                                                \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}T.Time}    & \shortstack{ \\ 13.5 \\ 8.5* }                      & w.i.p                                              & 14.5                                               & 3                                              & w.i.p                                              & 23                                                 & 4.5                                            & n/a                                                & 7.5                                                \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Comparing the Quantitative Effects of Software Maintenance on Three Open-Source Projects}
\label{tab:main-metrics}
\end{table}
\end{footnotesize}
```

The error I encountered today looked like this, leading me to think that `multicolumn` most likely existed at one point:

```
tlmgr install: package multicolumn not present in repository.
tlmgr: action install returned an error; continuing.
tlmgr: package repository https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: valid signature with expired key)
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

Comment: I know no `multicolumn` package. Aren't  you confusing with `multicol,`, per chance?

Comment: Fair question. I added context. Maybe I'm working with an outdated/invalid `Dockerfile` today, after all?

Comment: \multicolumn is a standard command and always defined. You don't need a package for it.

Comment: I've never heard of a package called `multicolumn` either. The `multicol` package has been around for a long time, for sure. It was most recently updated in November 2021, and its current version number is `1.9b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. It's a safe bet that `multicolumn` does not exist as a package and that I've been looking at some kind of invalid Dockerfile all along. I ran `tlmgr info | grep multicol` in my previously useful container/image and it revealed no signs of `multicolumn` existing.

Thanks: @bernard, @ulrike-fischer and @mico - for chiming in and putting a spotlight on what I needed to investigate.